# Simplifying a Boolean expression that has 3 variables in it

Tags: boolean-algebra

Problem:
Simplify the following expression using Boolean Algebra:
$$ z = (B + \overline C)(\overline B + C) +  \overline{ \overline A + B + \overline C} $$
Answer:
\begin{align*}
z &= (B + \overline C)(\overline B + C) + A \overline{B} C  \\
z &= \overline C \, \overline B + BC + A \overline{B} C  \\
z &= \overline B \, \overline C + C ( B + A \overline B ) \\
z &= \overline B \, \overline C + C ( A + B ) \\
z &= AC + BC + \overline B \, \overline C  \\
\end{align*}
However, the book gets:
$$ BC + \overline B ( \overline C + A ) $$
I believe both answers are right but I would like to know how to get the book's answer.

Comment: At first glance, one thing is you didn't convert AND to OR for ABC in your answer's first line.

Comment: @TonyM You are right. I will fix it.

Comment: @TonyM The error was in the question, not the first line of my answer. I now fixed the post.

Comment: The answers are not equivalent, and yours has an error between the 4th and 5th line.

Comment: Consider `ABC = 101` and check both expressions.

Comment: @EugeneSh Now that I have updated by post, I claim that the original expression, my answer and the book's answer all get $1$ for the case of $ABC = 101$.

Comment: Yes, now these are equivalent

Comment: This is an excellent example of how to ask a homework question.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday

Comment: @Meenie Leis I did not ask this exact question yesterday. I did ask a similar question. This is not a homework question for me. That is, I am not in school.

Comment: You must be kidding. It's the same boolean expression.  For which two different reductions were discussed

Comment: @MeenieLeis You are right. I did ask the same question twice. I did not realize that to now. I was going to delete it, but I got a warning from the system that I should not delete a question with answers so I am not going to delete it. If a moderator or some other person in authority wants to delete it, I have no problem with that. Thanks for catching the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your answer:
$$ z = AC + BC + \overline B \, \overline C 
$$

Now make the following transformation:
$$ z = AC(B+\overline B) + BC + \overline B \, \overline C 
$$
Expand:
$$ z = ABC+A\overline B C + BC + \overline B \, \overline C 
$$
Use the redundancy rule \$X+XY=X\$ on the first and third terms:

$$ z = BC + A\overline B C + \overline B  \overline C = $$
$$ = BC + \overline B(AC+\overline C) $$

Use another rule: \$X+\overline XY=X + Y\$ on the expression in parentheses:
$$ z = BC + \overline B(A+\overline C) $$

And now it is exactly the book answer.